# Is there a way to add or remove programs to/from my Ninite installer?

Tags: ninite

Ninite is awesome, but is there a way to add one more program to my installer? Or remove one program from my installer? Or do I have to go to [ninite.com](http://ninite.com), tick all the relevant boxes, and download a new package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't modify your current installer, but for the next time:

- Check the apps you want
- Click the **Get Your Ninite** button
- On the next page (where the download begins), you get a link named **change apps**
- Save this link to your bookmarks

This link brings you to the ninite page with all you apps pre-checked, so you can easily add/remove some apps as needed.

[image: Installer includes]

Comment: @CamJackson Have you considered changing the accepted answer to ByScript's answer?

Answer (score 5):

You couldn't do this with the free website based ninite software download- its a feature of  [ninite one](http://ninite.com/one) which is part of the paid [ninite pro](https://ninite.com/pro) service, as opposed to a standalone product.